# Alter password in TOAD by overriding password policy

Tags: sql, oracle, security

I want to alter password in TOAD, but I want to keep a password which does not fulfil the password policy set. How do I override the password policy while altering the password?

Comment: Who owns the database you're connecting to?

Comment: We don't, we just access it using a login credentials who has FULL ACCESS to the database, But i need a script to do this operation.

Answer (score 1):

Find the  profile of the user-

```
SQL> select profile from dba_users where username='USER1';

PROFILE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEFAULT
```

then alter the profile to set `password_verify_function` to `null`.

```
SQL> conn sys as sysdba


SQL> alter user user1 identified by user1;
alter user user1 identified by user1
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28003: password verification for the specified password failed
ORA-20026: Password must contain at least 1 special character(s)


SQL> alter profile default limit password_verify_function null;

Profile altered.

SQL> alter user c##_user1 identified by user1;

User altered.
```